# Issue while entering specific data to QLineEdit in Qt

Tags: qt

I am having an issue with entering values into QLineEdit. This is more of a logical issue. My requirement is that I want to restrict user to enter values between 60 to 150, that includes decimal values within this range i.e. 65.5 or 140.5 etc. I want to display a message to the user if he enters values outside this range.

My approach for this is like: I set the "maxLength" property of this "QLineEdit" to 5 in the ui designer, so that user can can enter only 5 characters like 140.5. Then on the "textChanged" slot I have written the following code:

```
void MyWidget::on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString text)
{
    if ((text.size() >= 3) && (text.toFloat() > 150 || text.toFloat() < 60))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
        ui->lineEdit->setText("");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(text);
    }
}
```

Also used the following code for validation like:

```
QRegExp rx("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
```

The above code works fine. The only problem is that message is not displayed if value is less that 60 on the first go, as I am checking the condition [B](text.size() >= 3)[/B]. Message is only displayed if text.size() >= 3. I am not able to put the proper logic for this case. Is it possible to change the logic to display the user for the range to be satisfied.
Please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider it extremely broken and annoying UI if message boxes pop up in my face as I type. Better display a warning label and/or disable the confirmation button and/or use a QDoubleValidator to prevent invalid input. Or use a QDoubleSpinBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
void number_test::Slot(const QString& str)

{
QString sttt = str;
bool bb = sttt.contains(QChar('.'));
if(!bb)
{
int nSize = sttt.size();
if(nSize == 1)
{
if(sttt.toInt() < 6 && sttt.toInt() != 1)
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
clear();
}
}
else if(nSize == 2)
{
if(sttt.toFloat() < 60.0)
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
clear();
}
}
else if(nSize >= 3)
{
if(sttt.toFloat() > 150.0)
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
clear();
}
}
}
else
{
int nSize = sttt.size();
if(nSize == 1)
{
if(sttt.toInt() < 6 && sttt.toInt() != 1)
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
clear();
}
}
else 
{
if(sttt.toFloat() > 150.0 || sttt.toFloat() < 60.0)
{
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
clear();
}
}
}
}
```

Please try these code for your question.

Comment: It's not working as per the requirement. When you enter only 2 digits, it displays the message i.e. when you enter the number 11 it displays the message, which is not expected because user might trying to enter number like 112.

Comment: If you connect to the textChanged signal the tests will fire everytime the user  changes the text. For instance from '1' to '11'. If you want the tests to fire only when the user is finished entering text you can connect to the textEdited signal.

Comment: It can work in my computer.Maybe something wrong don't happen in my test cases,I will modify it ,thank you !

Comment: Thanks Kim. I implemented your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case for the QDoubleValidator !!!

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublevalidator.html

```
QDoubleValidator *v = new QDoubleValidator(60.0,150.0);
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(v);
```

Edit: If you want to have the messagebox pop up on invalid texts, you could use the validator inside the slot you already use.

```
void MyWidget::on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString text)
{
      QDoubleValidator v(60.0,150.0);
      if(v.validate(text) != QValidator::Acceptable)
      {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
      }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but i think it should work more or less as the OP wants it too.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I have implemented the code as follows:

```
void MyWidget::on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString text)
{
    if(text.startsWith('.'))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
        ui->lineEdit->setText("");
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(text.at(2) == '.')
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
        ui->lineEdit->setText("");
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
        return;
    }
    if ((text.size() >= 3) && (text.toFloat() > 150 || text.toFloat() < 60))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
        ui->lineEdit->setText("");
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(text);
    }
}

void MyWidget::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()
{
    QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();
    if (text.toFloat() < 60)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "Range should be between 60 and 150.", QMessageBox::Ok);
        ui->lineEdit->setText("");
        ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
    }
    else
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(text);
    }
}
```